# Quill editor automatically removes all table tags (table, tbody, thead, tr, td, th)

Tags: reactjs, editor, quill, rich-text-editor

I am using Quill editor in one of the projects, I have a block of code that is similar to this

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>hey</th>
        <th>hey</th>
        <th>hey</th>
        <th>hey</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Preview :
[image]

I pasted this block of code into the HTML mode of Quill editor and the preview was fine, then I turned back into the non-html mode it changed its style completely, I switched back into HTML mode then I saw it changed my original block of code which is this

`<div>heyheyheyheyhellohellohellohello</div>`

[image]

I want to persist the original block of code, according to my investigation, Quill doesn't support some HTML tags but I don't have any solution till now